# Unable to push to Git Repository after adding a branch

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-push

I have a `Git` repository with about 4 branches. They are put up on `GitHub`. I recently created a new branch, named "demo2Full". Since creating that, I am unable to push to an earlier branch called "bugfixes". Here is what I did to create the new branch:

1. Created new branch "demo2Full" on GitHub, that is same as "bugfixes".
2. `git remote add demo2Full git@github-user:user/project_demo2Full.git`
3. On local machine: `git branch demo2Full` & `git checkout demo2Full`.

After that I switched back to "bugfixes" with `git checkout bugfixes` without any issues.

Now, when I do: `git push origin bugfixes`, I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have gone through a number of links, [including this one on GitHub.](https://help.github.com/articles/error-repository-not-found)
The `SSH` part works, and I have also checked the remotes with `git remote -v` and the config file at `.git/config` and found that there are no spelling mistakes etc. in the links.

Where am I going wrong?

**Edit**
Also, having a separate entry in the config file for each branch like:
`git@github-userName:userName/projectName_branchName.git` is correct?

Comment: It's weird though, if you already have an earlier branch called "bugfixes", then the command `git branch bugfixes` should normally have given you the following error `fatal: A branch named 'bugfixes' already exists.` So either I misunderstand or you are confusing repo's and branches in your question. Please clarify.

Comment: Why would we get that error? `git branch bugfixes` is used to switch from one branch to the other... right?

Comment: `git branch (branchname)` is for creating a new branch. `git checkout (branchname)` is for switching (http://gitref.org/branching/)

Comment: oops! you are right. i had added that mistakenly. the 'fatal: branch already exists' error did pop up when i tried to do `git branch bugfixes`. i will edit that in the question.

Comment: Cool, but still unclear to me. You're talking about a branch "bugfixes" but at first you state "I am unable to push to an earlier **repository** called "bugfixes""

Comment: good catch. corrected. Also, I have made an Edit toward the bottom of the question.

Comment: @Sriram Your url is incorrect IMO. Change it to `git@github.com:<username>/<repo_name>.git`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.git/config` file had an "incorrect" entry.

The origin was listed as: `url = git@github-userName:userName`.

Changing that to : `url = git@github-userName:userName/projectName.git` rectified the error.

I am still not clear about how that change happened in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the URL to `git@github.com:<username>/<repo_name>.git`. Ideally your .git/config should non-exhaustively include something like this -

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git@github.com:<username>/<project_name>.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

There's no need to add a remote alias for each branch. There's and should be only one alias for your repository on github.

Comment: I just pushed a change to another repo where the url was named like: `git@github-username:username/projectName.git`. This, I think, uses the `ssh` and not `https` as you suggest?